# Third highest salary department wise without using rank or other functions

Tags: sql-server, database

I want to find third highest salary department wise without using any functions such as `rank` or `row_number` or `dense_rank` in sql
My logic

```
select max(salary),deptno from emp
where salary not in
(select max(salary) from emp where salary not in
(select max(salary) from emp group by deptno)group by deptno)
group by deptno
```

This is my query.syntax is correct but it is not giving wright answer/result

Comment: Is `CROSS APPLY` allowed?

Comment: Your query is incomplete: `GROUP BY deptnoit is`, also can you reword your question? It isn't exactly clear what you're wanting.

Comment: And you haven't specified if you want 3rd highest **distinct** salary or just the 3rd highest. Ties are important.

Comment: And why wouldn't you want to use window functions? They are the perfect tool for this kind of questions.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job

```
select salary, deptno from emp e where 2 = 
(select count(distinct salary) from emp where
salary > e.salary and deptno = e.depto)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using MSSQL,

```
SELECT MAX(salary) as '3rdHighest', deptno
FROM EMP n WHERE 2 = 
                      (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT salary) FROM NewTbl 
                        WHERE salary > n. salary and deptno = n.deptno) 
GROUP BY deptno
```